# mybiblatexstyle

Tags: bibliographystyle

My Question is about the line:

`\newcommand{\mybiblatexstyle}{ieee}`

If I am right this line says that the bibliography and the citations are going to be formated in the IEEE Standard. But how can I adjust the way it will be shown in my document? I am using the Overleaf compiler to work on my thesis. I got a template from my university but its quite difficult to understand whats happening because we never got tought anything about LateX.

I want to clean up my references in the bibliography to look like this:

[image]

But whenever I will cite anything the DOI or ISSN Number will appear in the bibliography. I found out that I have to adjust the way Mendeley exports the .bib file by adjusting the csl file by removing the DOI part there. It never worked or I found no citation style which I can adjust to not mention DOI or ISSN. Then I tried to just delete the informations from the .bib file which worked quite well but its not a elegant way of resolving this issue and the Bibliography still contains the site on which my citation could be found.

Is there a way to implement biblatex via

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lauraPhd2016.bib}
```

so that I can adjust the style of the bibliography more easily or do I have to adjust the citation style completely via the mendeley manager?

Because when I comment `\newcommand{\mybiblatexstyle}{ieee}` out many errors appear and I cant find any documentations about this newcommand. When I found sites my browser or my computer won´t open the website...

The template I am using is https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/game-lab-graz-theses-template/rcrgfpyzmhwp

I am searching the whole day to resolve this but nothing works or i cant find anything helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

`\mybiblatexstyle` is just a local command, to be the text `apa` by default. You will not find any documentation on this other that the template file itself as it is just defined in this file, not a command that has any general use.

With the template example it runs without error if you change `apa` to `ieee`. It is used in just one place in the template that you link to, line 552 of `template/preamble.tex` which has

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, %% using "biber" to compile references (instead of "biblatex")
style=\mybiblatexstyle, %% see biblatex documentation
%style=alphabetic, %% see biblatex documentation
%dashed=\mybiblatexdashed, %% do *not* replace recurring reference authors with a dash
backref=\mybiblatexbackref, %% create backlings from references to citations
natbib=true, %% offering natbib-compatible commands
hyperref=true, %% using hyperref-package references
]{biblatex}  %% remove, if using BibTeX instead of biblatex
```

so changing the top level macro in `main.tex` is just the same as changing the `style=` key in the call to `biblatex`.